# Provision list instance with title and description from resources issue

Tags: list, list-definition, localization

I have created feature which contains list definition and list instance based on that definition. I also added feature resource files to localize it. I created invariant and pl-PL resource files. When I'm debugging, list definition and instance are created properly. The thing is, that when I access list instance in English, I'm getting list title and description like below:

```
$Resources:_FeatureId10b455ed-4436-4d16-a625-b179c85f1127,BlockListInstantionName;
```

When I'm accessing the same list instance, but in Polish (switching current language), title and description are properly displayed. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your format to pick the name from the Resource file is:

```
Name="$Resources:MyResources,ListInstance_News"
```

MyResources - name of the resources file (as described below)
ListInstance_News - the resource entry

And the name of Resources file (for the entry above) for English should be:

**MyResources.en-US.resx**

And deployed to:

**{SharePointRoot}\Resources**

Comment: So I have to specify language. I thought that invariant resources would take care of that.